# concatenate list of dataframes by index in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a question for and hope you can help me with. I am stuck and can't get this to work.
I have a list of 3 list-DataFrames (3X5) like this:

```
[[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5],
 [df11, df12, df13, df14, df15],
 [df21, df22, df23, df24, df25]]
```

What I'd like to achieve is to concatenate the DataFrames into one list DataFrame (ie dfs) based on the list index:

```
dfs = [dfs1, dfs2, dfs3, dfs4, dfs5]
```

with

```
dfs1 = pd.concat([df1, df11, df21])
dfs2 = pd.concat([df2, df12, df22])
dfs3 = pd.concat([df3, df13, df23])   
dfs4 = pd.concat([df4, df14, df24])
dfs5 = pd.concat([df5, df15, df25])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and store concatenated dataframes into a list of 5 elements

```
lst = [[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5],
       [df11, df12, df13, df14, df15],
       [df21, df22, df23, df24, df25]]
dfs = [pd.concat(x) for x in zip(*lst)]
```

```
>>> len(dfs)
5

>>> dfs[0]
    0   1   2
0  16  14  13  # <- df1
1  18  17  12
2  12  13  16
3  11  16  17
4  11  18  17
0  18  13  12  # <- df11
1  14  18  12
2  11  17  13
3  17  18  15
4  18  18  12
0  16  13  15  # <- df21
1  16  11  18
2  12  18  15
3  16  14  14
4  17  12  11

>>> dfs[4]
    0   1   2
0  52  54  54  # <- df5
1  52  53  57
2  56  51  53
3  54  58  52
4  57  51  51
0  51  58  58  # <- df15
1  57  54  56
2  56  58  58
3  53  55  56
4  53  56  53
0  51  53  54  # <- df25
1  52  55  58
2  52  54  56
3  58  54  56
4  52  58  56
```

Note: if you need to concatenate along index axis, use `pd.concat(..., axis=1)` to get a wide dataframe instead of long one.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
lst = [[pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1+i*10, 9+i*10, (5, 3)))
        for i in range(1, 6)] for j in range(0, 3)]
```